# Let $G$ be an abelian group such that $|G|$ is an odd integer. Show that the product of all the elements in $G$ is $e.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

How do you show the product of the elements in $G$ is $e$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**: Pair elements $g$ with $g^{-1}$. Since $|G|$ is odd, we know that there are no non-identity elements for which $g = g^{-1}$.

---

To use the fact that $|G|$ is odd, suppose that $g = g^{-1}$. Then $g^2 = 1$, implying something about the order of $g$.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how $|G|$ being odd allows us to conclude that there are no non-identity elements for which $g=g^{-1}$?

Comment: Why the downvote? If someone would like to point out an error, omission, or something wrong, I'd happily address it.

Comment: @user Thank you for responding. Although I disagree with your policy, it is understandable. Would you prefer if I were to add a spoiler box around the second point?

Comment: So I understand the concept but I'm not sure if my proof is well enough to well, prove it. I understand that every element has its inverse, thus there are a pair of an elements and there are n amounts of those, thus creating an even size for G, but we know the identity is also in the group, thus even+1=odd.. is the correct logic?